# Page not visible on cordova app using ios 7

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ios7

Sorry for the particularly vague question, I am having an issue were the views in my app are not visible initially, you can press on the screen and the links and other items work, you just cannot see them for some reason.

This only happends iOS 7  it appears to work as expected on iOS8 and android.

```
cordova -version 4.1.2

@license AngularJS v1.2.27
```

Is this a common issue/bug that anyone has had?

Comment: Could you maybe provide picture or some other clarification about what exactly shows on the screen? What happens when you click the links (aren't they invisible at first too?), does it work then? Is it just black or white? Is there any JS errors?

Comment: Yeah, i haven't really given you much to go off, basically the ng-view part of the screen is black. but the header and footer are visible, I can't provide screen shots unfortunately. The links function as expected and there are no js errors.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was related to `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` removing this from the container fixed the issue